# Nano and Midnight Commander don't work on Docker for Windows beta

Tags: docker

I use Docker for Windows 10. Arrow controls don't work on nano, vim and midnight commander. Have encoding problems

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With mc you can press F9 to select top menu. Then navigate to Options->Learn keys using only letter keys. The needed key will be highlighted. So it will be "F9 o k" and then follow the instructions. Worked for me.

[image: example]

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Tested with the same terminal on docker and a remote server. Docker clearly has some problems with input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `legacy mode` in powershell (Powershell > Properties > "Options" tab) if you already have updates installed (enables new features described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/mt427362(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

Works fine without encoding problems and navigation glitches.

Please, view screenshot: [Alpine with installed Midnight Commander in Windows Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPJba.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Install and run bash, run it and than run mc from bash.

```
apk update && apk add bash mc
bash
mc
```

Encoding problem can be solved in Options->Appearance in mc itself.